# How to use TensorFlow metrics in Keras

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, keras-2

There seem to be several threads/issues on this already but it doesn't appear to me that this has been solved:

[How can I use tensorflow metric function within keras models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158719/how-can-i-use-tensorflow-metric-function-within-keras-models)

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/6050

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3230

People seem to either run into problems around variable initialization or the metric being 0.

I need to calculate different segmentation metrics and would like to include [tf.metric.mean_iou](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/mean_iou) in my Keras model. This is the best I have been able to come up with so far:

```
def mean_iou(y_true, y_pred):
   score, up_opt = tf.metrics.mean_iou(y_true, y_pred, NUM_CLASSES)
   K.get_session().run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
   return score

model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=[mean_iou])
```

This code does not throw any errors but mean_iou always returns 0. I believe this is because *up_opt* is not evaluated. I have seen that prior to TF 1.3 [people have suggested](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/6050#issuecomment-301684525) to use something along the lines of *control_flow_ops.with_dependencies([up_opt], score)* to achieve this. This does not seem possible in TF 1.3 anymore.

In summary, how do I evaluate TF 1.3 metrics in Keras 2.0.6? This seems like quite an important feature.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 11):

you can still use`control_dependencies`

```
def mean_iou(y_true, y_pred):
   score, up_opt = tf.metrics.mean_iou(y_true, y_pred, NUM_CLASSES)
   K.get_session().run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
   with tf.control_dependencies([up_opt]):
       score = tf.identity(score)
   return score
```

Comment: This runs but is extremely slow (about 10x slower compared to not compiling the model with this additional metric). I suspect to be the *score = tf.identity(score)* line the reason for this. Any ideas?

Comment: that's not the reason, the complexity of `tf.identity` is constant (1), it dosn't make any difference . the reason is the computation of another metrics.

Comment: This is another implementation of mean_iou: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50266195/6897083

Comment: If I try this I get an Attribute error on `get_shape()` for my `y_pred` as it is a numpy array. Do I need to change them to something?

Comment: I have managed to get working [every available metric in Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics) within Keras and I've wrapped my code into the python package [extra-keras-metrics](https://github.com/LucaCappelletti94/extra_keras_metrics) using this solution.

Answer (score 1):

There were 2 keys to getting this working for me.  The first was using

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
```

To initialize TF variables after using the TF functions (and compiling), but before doing `model.fit()`.  You've got that in your initial example, but most other examples show `tf.global_variables_initializer()`, which didn't work for me.

The other thing I discovered is the op_update object, which is returned as the second part of the tuple from many TF metrics, is what we want.  The other portion seems to be 0 when TF metrics are used with Keras.  So your IOU metric should look like:

```
def mean_iou(y_true, y_pred):
   return tf.metrics.mean_iou(y_true, y_pred, NUM_CLASSES)[1]

from keras import backend as K

K.get_session().run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

model.fit(...)
```