# How can I specify a loss function to be quadratic weighted kappa in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

My understanding is that keras requires loss functions to have the signature:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
```

I am trying to use `sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score`, which takes
(y1, y2, labels=None, weights=None, sample_weight=None)`

If I use it as is:

```
model.compile(loss=metrics.cohen_kappa_score,
              optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Then the `weights` won't be set. I want to set that to `quadtratic`. Is there some what to pass this through?

Comment: `sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score` is not a valid Keras loss, because it doesn't operate on Keras tensors

Comment: @rvinas Could something like sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score be accessed via https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/ (Keras' Scikit Learn API)? That might allow OP to do it basically this way

Comment: @seisvelas I don't think so - these wrappers allow to use Keras models in your Scikit-learn workflow, but not the opposite. The only solution I see is to implement `sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score` using Keras operations

Comment: @seisvelas How would I implement with Keras operations?

Comment: Maybe the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46858016/keras-custom-loss-function-to-pass-arguments-other-than-y-true-and-y-pred) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two steps in implementing a parameterized custom loss function (`cohen_kappa_score`) in Keras. Since there are implemented function for your needs, there is no need for you to implement it yourself. However, according to [TensorFlow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/metrics/cohen_kappa), `sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score` does not support weighted matrix.
Therefore, I suggest TensorFlow's implementation of cohen_kappa. However, using TensorFlow in Keras is not that easy...
According to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947351/how-to-use-tensorflow-metrics-in-keras), they used `control_dependencies` to use a TensorFlow metric in Keras. Here is a example:

```
import keras.backend as K
def _cohen_kappa(y_true, y_pred, num_classes, weights=None, metrics_collections=None, updates_collections=None, name=None):
   kappa, update_op = tf.contrib.metrics.cohen_kappa(y_true, y_pred, num_classes, weights, metrics_collections, updates_collections, name)
   K.get_session().run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
   with tf.control_dependencies([update_op]):
      kappa = tf.identity(kappa)
   return kappa
```

Since [Keras loss functions](https://keras.io/losses/) take `(y_true, y_pred)` as parameters, you need a wrapper function that returns another function. Here is some code:

```
def cohen_kappa_loss(num_classes, weights=None, metrics_collections=None, updates_collections=None, name=None):
   def cohen_kappa(y_true, y_pred):
      return -_cohen_kappa(y_true, y_pred, num_classes, weights, metrics_collections, updates_collections, name)
   return cohen_kappa
```

Finally, you can use it as follows in Keras:

```
# get the loss function and set parameters
model_cohen_kappa = cohen_kappa_loss(num_classes=3,weights=weights)
# compile model
model.compile(loss=model_cohen_kappa,
          optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Regarding using the Cohen-Kappa metric as a loss function. In general it is possible to use weighted kappa as a loss function. Here is a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317072987_Weighted_kappa_loss_function_for_multi-class_classification_of_ordinal_data_in_deep_learning) using weighted kappa as a loss function for multi-class classification.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but i ran into to following problem:

ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 5 for 'loss_7/dense_8_loss/cohen_kappa/remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,5].

any ideas?

Comment: This solution is not using the quadratic weighted kappa.

Comment: Did you find a solution for the quadratic kappa score? I am suffering from the same issue.

Comment: not yet :( but ill try to make a version for tensorflow 2, as it seems easier.

Answer (score 4):

You can define it as a custom loss and yes you are right that `keras` accepts only two arguments in the loss function. Here is how you can define your loss:

```
def get_cohen_kappa(weights=None):
    def cohen_kappa_score(y_true, y_pred):
        """
        Define your code here. You can now use `weights` directly
        in this function
        """
        return score
    return cohen_kappa_score
```

Now you can pass this function to your model as:

```
model.compile(loss=get_cohen_kappa_score(weights=weights),
              optimizer='adam')
model.fit(...)
```

Comment: Modified my question to indicate the `quadratic weighted kappa`.

Comment: Just plug in the logic in the inner function and it will work as expected

Comment: One more thing. `Kappa` is a `metric`, why do you want to use it as a loss function?

Comment: I want to minimize the kappa, so doesn’t it make sense to use it as a loss function?

Comment: you can use any metric as a loss function, as long as it is differentiable